# How do I call Bootstrap CDN to JSF

Tags: jsf, xhtml, cdn

My professor is making my class use JSF to build our website, and I'm not too familiar with the xhtml syntax. I want to use Bootstrap since I'm used to using it for html.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

But I get this error:

> Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 10] The element type
>   "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good professor.

close your tag on:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

you should also add `type="text/css"`  or use `<h:outputStylesheet` if your css is local

Comment: hmmm I would not call this a 'good professor' per say. Teaching jsf yes. but teaching students how to use google for troubleshooting should have a high priority... ;-)

Comment: lets say this was an emergency.. he will manage on his own from now on ;)